# Querying Dispatch table by passing two dates parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to view an order detail by say; weekly, monthly order by passing two dates parameters. I have tried several but it is returning null.

this is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT A.Dispatch_ID,   
A.Dispatched_Date, 
A.Product_ID, 
A.Product_Code, 
A.Product_Loaded, 
A.Meter_Ticket_ID, 
A.Marketer_ID, 
A.Dispatched_Truck, 
A.Loaded_Quantity, 
A.Loading_Depot, 
A.Over_Loaded, 
A.Under_Loaded,
A.User_Name, 
A.Employee_ID, 
B.Dispatched_Date AS Dispatched_Date1 
FROM ((SELECT Dispatch_ID, Format(Dispatched_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS Dispatched_Date, Product_ID, Product_Code, Product_Loaded, Meter_Ticket_ID, Marketer_ID, Dispatched_Truck, Loaded_Quantity, Loading_Depot, Over_Loaded, Under_Loaded, User_Name, Employee_ID FROM Dispatched_Entry) A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Dispatch_ID, Format(Dispatched_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS Dispatched_Date, Product_ID, Product_Code, Product_Loaded, Meter_Ticket_ID, Marketer_ID, Dispatched_Truck, Loaded_Quantity, Loading_Depot, Over_Loaded, Under_Loaded, User_Name, Employee_ID FROM Dispatched_Entry Dispatched_Entry_1)B ON A.Product_ID = B.Product_ID)
WHERE A.Dispatched_Date =? AND B.Dispatched_Date =?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters into a SQL query via a [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) instance, use named parameters. Here's a crude example in C#:

```cs
var query = @"SELECT A.Dispatch_ID, 
              ...
              WHERE A.Dispatched_Date = @dateA AND B.Dispatched_Date = @dateB";
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateA", someDateA);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateB", someDateB);
```

There are further examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

To configure the `SqlDataSource` directly in ASP.NET, like this:

```
<asp:dropdownlist
   id="DropDownListA"
   runat="server"
   autopostback="True">
   ...
</asp:dropdownlist>

<asp:dropdownlist
   id="DropDownListB"
   runat="server"
   autopostback="True">
   ...
</asp:dropdownlist>

<asp:sqldatasource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
    selectcommand="SELECT A.Dispatch_ID, 
                   ...
                   WHERE A.Dispatched_Date = @dateA AND B.Dispatched_Date = @dateB">
    <selectparameters>
      <asp:controlparameter name="dateA" controlid="DropDownListA" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
      <asp:controlparameter name="dateB" controlid="DropDownListB" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
    </selectparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your swift response. I'm using a sql datasource and all I'm trying to achieve is to been able to use two drop down lists to select different date based on the query parameters.

Comment: @user3036566 See my updated answer for further examples

Comment: I've tried implementing this but it's still firing blank.

Comment: @user3036566 Were there any errors or was it just blank? Also, can you show a bit more of your code?

Comment: There was an error when I tried to write the parameters as `A.Dispatched_Date = @dateA AND B.Dispatched_Date = @dateB` and error was 'no value was selected for one or more parameters' but when I changed it to `A.Dispatched_Date = ? AND B.Dispatched_Date = ?` there was no error but it returned nothing.